# (Python 3.8) How can I turn a variable into a list without a seperator?

Tags: python, list

I want to have a user input a number, and that number is turned into a list named digits. I need to be able to do this without any seperators like space or comma...

```
number=int(input())
digits=[]

#

print (digits)
```

Example: 
User input: 808 
Code output: [8,0,8]

Comment: You can use call `list()` on a string to turn it into a list of characters. E.g `list('808')`

Comment: This would be easier if you kept the input as a string instead of immediately converting it to an integer.  Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return from `input()` is a string which is already iterable by-character!

Assuming all the members of the input are really numbers, you can iterate over it, converting each to an `int()` as you go in a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
digits = [int(x) for x in input()]
```

this is a shorthand for a loop like

```py
digits = []
source_string = input("enter digits: ")
for value in list(source_string):
    digits.append(int(value))
```

Some error-handling `(ValueError, TypeError)` may be wanted to nicely handle non-int inputs the user may provide

Comment: `for value in list(source_string):` why did you use `list` on `source_string`?

Comment: ah, it's my hope this makes it clearer both what will be iterated over and that simply `list()` on a string makes a list of the characters; there's no practical reason to do more work than the comprehension does

Comment: No, it absolutely doesn't make it clear, it *confused* because you don't do it in comprehension, and because it does absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are an _expert_, while I am illustrating two distinct things in attempt to provoke that very question in a small space; why is it needed here and not in the other position (it of course isn't!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list(map(int, input()))
```